# Suppress any write statement from BAPI_XXX

Tags: abap

I used BAPI_SHIPMENT_CREATE to create a shipment. After that, I display an ALV. When I press back from ALV, I have a list with a text output from this BAPI.

Does it exist a method to suppress this output? I want to go to selection screen, when I press back from ALV.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's very unusual that a BAPI uses WRITE. If that's true, then make sure whether the WRITE comes from the standard code or from an enhancement (breakpoint on statement WRITE for instance). If it comes from the standard code, then you may contact the SAP support to make them correct it.

Comment: You're right, I debugged and the WRITE came from a user exit .. I solved that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the FM with the “destination none” option to create a new LUW. I think that will suppress the output.

Comment: Yes, I used that, but the BAPI does not create the shipment in this case.

Comment: If you run the FM with the "destination 'NONE'" but it "does not create the shipment", it means that the updates are probably done via an update task, so you must also call the function module BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT **with the destination 'NONE'** to trigger the update task.